# The inequality. Regional olympiad 2015

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c$ - the positive real numbers, and $ab+bc+ca=1$
Prove that $\sqrt{a+\frac{1}{a}}+\sqrt{b+\frac{1}{b}}+\sqrt{c+\frac{1}{c}} \geqslant 2(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})$

Probably, we should use these facts:

$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{abc}$

$(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2$

But I don't know how to use them. Please, help.

Comment: Problem proposed by me

Answer (score 17):

We have 
$$
\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a+\frac{1}{a}}=\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a+\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a}}=\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a+\frac{bc}{a}+b+c}\ge\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{2\sqrt{bc}+b+c}=\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{\left(\sqrt b+\sqrt c\right)^2}=\sum_{cyc} \left(\sqrt b+\sqrt c\right)=2\left(\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c\right)
$$
as desired.

Note: The inequality is due to the well known inequality between the arithmetic mean and the geometric mean, which states that:
$$
\frac{a_1+…+a_n}{n}\ge\left(a_1\cdots a_n\right)^\frac{1}{n}
$$
Taking $n=2$, $a_1=a$ and $a_2=\frac{bc}{a}$ this yields:
$$
\frac{a+\frac{bc}{a}}{2}\ge\left(a\cdot\frac{bc}{a}\right)^\frac12=\sqrt{bc}\iff a+\frac{bc}{a}\ge2\sqrt{bc}
$$
This is, as shown above, enough to prove your inequality.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $a+\frac{bc}{a} \geq 2\sqrt{bc}$?

Comment: @Joffan that's AM-GM inequality with two variables

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Schwarz we have
$$
\sqrt{a + \frac{1}{a}} = \sqrt{a + b + c + \frac{bc}{a}} \geq \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{\frac{bc}{a}}\right)
$$
and similarly
$$
\sqrt{b + \frac{1}{b}} \geq \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{\frac{ca}{b}}\right)
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{c + \frac{1}{c}} \geq \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}\right).
$$
Thus
$$
\sqrt{a + \frac{1}{a}} + \sqrt{b + \frac{1}{b}} + \sqrt{c + \frac{1}{c}} 
\geq \frac{1}{2}\left(3\left(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c}\right) + \frac{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{c}} + \frac{\sqrt{b}\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{a}} + \frac{\sqrt{c}\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} \right) \geq 2\left(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c}\right).
$$